# From openid-configuration to user JWT information by curl

Tags: curl, jwt, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I am looking for user's information full steps from OpenID configuration to user information by curl in Keycloak.

I can get openid-configuration API  via curl

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm/.well-known/openid-configuration'
```

I got this result but have no idea what is next step.
Can you someone help me how to get a JWT token and get a user information by curl commend?

```
{
  "issuer": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm",
  "authorization_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
  "token_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token",
  "introspection_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect",
  "userinfo_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo",
  "end_session_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/logout",
  "frontchannel_logout_session_supported": true,
  "frontchannel_logout_supported": true,
  "jwks_uri": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/certs",
  "check_session_iframe": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/login-status-iframe.html",
  "grant_types_supported": [
    "authorization_code",
    "implicit",
    "refresh_token",
    "password",
    "client_credentials",
    "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code",
    "urn:openid:params:grant-type:ciba"
  ],
  "response_types_supported": [
    "code",
    "none",
    "id_token",
    "token",
    "id_token token",
    "code id_token",
    "code token",
    "code id_token token"
  ],
  "subject_types_supported": [
    "public",
    "pairwise"
  ],
  "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": [
    "PS384",
    "ES384",
    "RS384",
    "HS256",
    "HS512",
    "ES256",
    "RS256",
    "HS384",
    "ES512",
    "PS256",
    "PS512",
    "RS512"
  ],
  "id_token_encryption_alg_values_supported": [
    "RSA-OAEP",
    "RSA-OAEP-256",
    "RSA1_5"
  ],
  "id_token_encryption_enc_values_supported": [
    "A256GCM",
    "A192GCM",
    "A128GCM",
    "A128CBC-HS256",
    "A192CBC-HS384",
    "A256CBC-HS512"
  ],
  "userinfo_signing_alg_values_supported": [
    "PS384",
    "ES384",
    "RS384",
    "HS256",
    "HS512",
    "ES256",
    "RS256",
    "HS384",
    "ES512",
    "PS256",
    "PS512",
    "RS512",
    "none"
  ],
  "request_object_signing_alg_values_supported": [
    "PS384",
    "ES384",
    "RS384",
    "HS256",
    "HS512",
    "ES256",
    "RS256",
    "HS384",
    "ES512",
    "PS256",
    "PS512",
    "RS512",
    "none"
  ],
  "request_object_encryption_alg_values_supported": [
    "RSA-OAEP",
    "RSA-OAEP-256",
    "RSA1_5"
  ],
  "request_object_encryption_enc_values_supported": [
    "A256GCM",
    "A192GCM",
    "A128GCM",
    "A128CBC-HS256",
    "A192CBC-HS384",
    "A256CBC-HS512"
  ],
  "response_modes_supported": [
    "query",
    "fragment",
    "form_post",
    "query.jwt",
    "fragment.jwt",
    "form_post.jwt",
    "jwt"
  ],
  "registration_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm/clients-registrations/openid-connect",
  "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
    "private_key_jwt",
    "client_secret_basic",
    "client_secret_post",
    "tls_client_auth",
    "client_secret_jwt"
  ],
  "token_endpoint_auth_signing_alg_values_supported": [
    "PS384",
    "ES384",
    "RS384",
    "HS256",
    "HS512",
    "ES256",
    "RS256",
    "HS384",
    "ES512",
    "PS256",
    "PS512",
    "RS512"
  ],
  "introspection_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
    "private_key_jwt",
    "client_secret_basic",
    "client_secret_post",
    "tls_client_auth",
    "client_secret_jwt"
  ],
  "introspection_endpoint_auth_signing_alg_values_supported": [
    "PS384",
    "ES384",
    "RS384",
    "HS256",
    "HS512",
    "ES256",
    "RS256",
    "HS384",
    "ES512",
    "PS256",
    "PS512",
    "RS512"
  ],
  "authorization_signing_alg_values_supported": [
    "PS384",
    "ES384",
    "RS384",
    "HS256",
    "HS512",
    "ES256",
    "RS256",
    "HS384",
    "ES512",
    "PS256",
    "PS512",
    "RS512"
  ],
  "authorization_encryption_alg_values_supported": [
    "RSA-OAEP",
    "RSA-OAEP-256",
    "RSA1_5"
  ],
  "authorization_encryption_enc_values_supported": [
    "A256GCM",
    "A192GCM",
    "A128GCM",
    "A128CBC-HS256",
    "A192CBC-HS384",
    "A256CBC-HS512"
  ],
  "claims_supported": [
    "aud",
    "sub",
    "iss",
    "auth_time",
    "name",
    "given_name",
    "family_name",
    "preferred_username",
    "email",
    "acr"
  ],
  "claim_types_supported": [
    "normal"
  ],
  "claims_parameter_supported": true,
  "scopes_supported": [
    "openid",
    "roles",
    "profile",
    "web-origins",
    "microprofile-jwt",
    "phone",
    "address",
    "offline_access",
    "email"
  ],
  "request_parameter_supported": true,
  "request_uri_parameter_supported": true,
  "require_request_uri_registration": true,
  "code_challenge_methods_supported": [
    "plain",
    "S256"
  ],
  "tls_client_certificate_bound_access_tokens": true,
  "revocation_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/revoke",
  "revocation_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
    "private_key_jwt",
    "client_secret_basic",
    "client_secret_post",
    "tls_client_auth",
    "client_secret_jwt"
  ],
  "revocation_endpoint_auth_signing_alg_values_supported": [
    "PS384",
    "ES384",
    "RS384",
    "HS256",
    "HS512",
    "ES256",
    "RS256",
    "HS384",
    "ES512",
    "PS256",
    "PS512",
    "RS512"
  ],
  "backchannel_logout_supported": true,
  "backchannel_logout_session_supported": true,
  "device_authorization_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth/device",
  "backchannel_token_delivery_modes_supported": [
    "poll",
    "ping"
  ],
  "backchannel_authentication_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/ext/ciba/auth",
  "backchannel_authentication_request_signing_alg_values_supported": [
    "PS384",
    "ES384",
    "RS384",
    "ES256",
    "RS256",
    "ES512",
    "PS256",
    "PS512",
    "RS512"
  ],
  "require_pushed_authorization_requests": false,
  "pushed_authorization_request_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/ext/par/request",
  "mtls_endpoint_aliases": {
    "token_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token",
    "revocation_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/revoke",
    "introspection_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect",
    "device_authorization_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth/device",
    "registration_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm/clients-registrations/openid-connect",
    "userinfo_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo",
    "pushed_authorization_request_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/ext/par/request",
    "backchannel_authentication_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/ext/ciba/auth"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is step for get user information from get openid-configuration

1 get access token URL

```
TOKEN_URL=$(curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/test/.well-known/openid-configuration' | jq -r '.token_endpoint')
echo $TOKEN_URL
```

result

```
http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

2 get ID token form #1

```
ID_TOKEN=$(curl --location --request POST "$TOKEN_URL" \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=admin-cli' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=openid' \
--data-urlencode 'username=user' \
--data-urlencode 'password=1234' | jq -r '.id_token')

echo $ID_TOKEN
```

result

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJrTXNKN25mdUFpYWFBYXhZeFp2WXo3WWVFaVh6Nk5hZzV6LXMyazFreUpNIn0.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.EFxqpiFkevbyipH2iSXRtYufTz-DAeC7Hd8a2Oz8zyhJN8LLu8yXJGgKRDpqkBvhbALo51CEbzlp9l0a5LDmDLAqOABS4nRdB5QFw69nCngACEirPyw-rMmvM7flsM3i4Yyl49kX8DZ2Y-E5KSuUIDN2-qe8DYFlJh-pw5oGRa6pKAdjyJ72hUP5tCfFGmDi_iU_6nSFXBZPXG0pETTQ_OqW6OFE1xAjp5dV0GuSjHKa8q0cDBkUmWnj0zpxQB0TQjh6e3WkSrJNmnWT4mqoUbwjDHXKelw-P6jbbewTAMugA01uPJWDH1sUBfkpJWTM9BHo3-kXEMYLsLjh5PQeuQ
```

3 decode ID token

```
jwtd() {
    if [[ -x $(command -v jq) ]]; then
         jq -R 'split(".") | .[0],.[1] | @base64d | fromjson' <<< "${1}"
         echo "Signature: $(echo "${1}" | awk -F'.' '{print $3}')"
    fi
}

jwtd $ID_TOKEN
```

result

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT",
  "kid": "kMsJ7nfuAiaaAaxYxZvYz7YeEiXz6Nag5z-s2k1kyJM"
}
{
  "exp": 1664160894,
  "iat": 1664160594,
  "auth_time": 0,
  "jti": "b27a7c2d-5d07-41ef-af21-59074e14ad24",
  "iss": "http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/test",
  "aud": "admin-cli",
  "sub": "3912c6d0-f210-4bed-8c56-70364d228add",
  "typ": "ID",
  "azp": "admin-cli",
  "session_state": "100965e0-2210-4be5-903e-c834f4cbda48",
  "at_hash": "UpaF7tozlKkgtGiZFCO3VQ",
  "acr": "1",
  "sid": "100965e0-2210-4be5-903e-c834f4cbda48",
  "email_verified": false,
  "preferred_username": "user",
  "email": "user@test.com"
}
Signature: EFxqpiFkevbyipH2iSXRtYufTz-DAeC7Hd8a2Oz8zyhJN8LLu8yXJGgKRDpqkBvhbALo51CEbzlp9l0a5LDmDLAqOABS4nRdB5QFw69nCngACEirPyw-rMmvM7flsM3i4Yyl49kX8DZ2Y-E5KSuUIDN2-qe8DYFlJh-pw5oGRa6pKAdjyJ72hUP5tCfFGmDi_iU_6nSFXBZPXG0pETTQ_OqW6OFE1xAjp5dV0GuSjHKa8q0cDBkUmWnj0zpxQB0TQjh6e3WkSrJNmnWT4mqoUbwjDHXKelw-P6jbbewTAMugA01uPJWDH1sUBfkpJWTM9BHo3-kXEMYLsLjh5PQeuQ
```

I referenced [Decoding JSON Web Tokens (JWTs) from the Linux command line](https://prefetch.net/blog/2020/07/14/decoding-json-web-tokens-jwts-from-the-linux-command-line/)